# Check if iPhone is paired with apple watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

In my app,

I need to find if my phone is paired with a apple watch and get some information about the paired watch like its name. I tried reading the documentation but I couldn't seem to find any thing specific to my use case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: unfortunately there is currently no way to detect whether apple watch is connected or not.

Comment: Can we do this reachable/connected check without apple watch companion app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So since WatchOS 2 that is possible !

You have to do on iPhone side :

First :

```
import WatchConnectivity
```

Then :

```
   if WCSession.isSupported() { // check if the device support to handle an Apple Watch
        let session = WCSession.default()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate() // activate the session

        if session.isPaired { // Check if the iPhone is paired with the Apple Watch
                // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

I hope It would help you :)

Comment: Worth noting that before you call `paired` (or `isPaired` in Obj-C) you should set the session's delegate and call `activateSession()`. If you fail to do this, `paired` will always return `false`/`NO`.

Comment: Is it possible to check reachability without having an watch app?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Yes. I answered the question as well.

Answer (score 6):

The best you can do is write to a shared NSUserDefaults value the first time the user opens your WK app, then check for that value in your iOS app. Beyond that there's no info you can get.

Comment: this seems ok! But if want to have a alternative behavior in my iphone app based on whether apple watch is connected or not then the above solution might not be of help!

Answer (score 3):

The idea is taken from @BilalReffas answer, but in WatchOS versions greater than 2.1 `activate()` method is asynchronous, so the offered solution won't work (it always returns `false`, even if watch is connected)

Firstly import SDK

```
import WatchConnectivity
```

Then implement session activation request

```
if WCSession.isSupported() { // check if the device support to handle an Apple Watch
    let session = WCSession.default
    session.delegate = self
    session.activate() // activate the session
}
```

Then implement methods from `WCSessionDelegate`

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if activationState == .activated && session.isPaired { // Check if the iPhone is paired with the Apple Watch
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```