# How to track in iOS app if user has Apple Watch without watch extension?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch

I want to know if my users have Apple Watch. If many user do, so I will develop Apple Watch application extension for my iOS app. Can I know if even watch is not paired?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457558/check-if-iphone-is-paired-with-apple-watch

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the [WatchConnectivity framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity). Especially, the [isPaired](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615665-ispaired) method of `WCSession` should solve your problem.

In your iPhone app's `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method, set up and activate the WatchConnectivity session, since `isPaired` only returns a valid value for an activated session.

```
//Set up WatchConnectivity
if WCSession.isSupported() {
   let session = WCSession.default()
   session.delegate = self
   session.activate()
}
```

In `func session(activationDidCompleteWith)` you can check if the iPhone is paired with an Apple Watch or not using this line of code:
`let userHasAppleWatch = session.isPaired`.